# I cannot understand what is the important of this

Tags: python

```
def edits1(word):
  "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
  letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
  deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
  transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
  replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
  inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
  return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
```

This method was copied form python code which was used to predict a word when we give a input.I want to know why it is important to use 'R' in `R for c in letters` .

Comment: There is no `R for c in letters` in the code. `L, R` presumably stands for left and right string in a pair (2-tuple), as constructed in the `splits =` line. Also, this is invalid Python - always preserve original indentation when you copy Python, because indentation is part of the language.

Comment: I used this link-https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]   can you describe how this line works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `splits` looks like this:

```
[('', 'word'), ('w', 'ord'), ('wo', 'rd'), ('wor', 'd'), ('word', '')]
```

The subsequent assignments use `L` (left) and `R` (right) to refer to each pair of elements in this list. So, for the 2nd element, `L == 'w'` and `R == 'ord'`.

If we take those values of `L` and `R`, then this line:

```
transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
```

gives `'w' + 'r' + 'o' + 'd'`, in other words it exchanges the first two letters of `R` so that `'ord'` becomes `'rod'`.